# How to select a random row from a Pervasive PSQL table

Tags: sql, random, pervasive-sql

In [Pervasive PSQL](http://www.pervasive.com/) (specifically), using a sql select statement, how can you select a random row from a table that has no numeric IDs?

Comment: What version of PSQL are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 11 with service pack 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *seems* to work for me using PSQL v11.30.

```
create table chartest (f1 char (10), f2 char(10), f3 char(10));
insert into chartest values ('a','a','a');
insert into chartest values ('b','b','b');
insert into chartest values ('c','c','c');
insert into chartest values ('d','d','d');
insert into chartest values ('e','e','e');
insert into chartest values ('f','f','f');
select top 1 * from chartest order by newid()
```

Which I ran several times and got:

```
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
f1           f2           f3        
==========   ==========   ==========
e            e            e         
1 row was affected.
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
f1           f2           f3        
==========   ==========   ==========
c            c            c         
1 row was affected.
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
f1           f2           f3        
==========   ==========   ==========
b            b            b         
1 row was affected.
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
f1           f2           f3        
==========   ==========   ==========
f            f            f         
1 row was affected.
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
```

Comment: Do you understand why that works, logically? What does order by newid() really mean?

Comment: order by rand() seems to work too. I wonder what's really happening behind the scenes and which is better. I guess it just generates a random number for each row and then orders by that random number. Is that what you think too?

Comment: Mirtheil, can you take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51625943/ignore-locked-records-during-pervasive-psql-update-statement) too? No one else has replied.