# Ignore Locked Records During Pervasive PSQL Update Statement

Tags: sql-update, deadlock, pervasive, pervasive-sql

Is there way to tell Pervasive PSQL to ignore locked records during an standard SQL Update Statement?

I have an [update](http://docs.actian.com/psql/PSQLv11/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=sqlref/syntaxref.03.90.html) statement that needs to run daily on a [Pervasive PSQL](http://www.pervasive.com/) 11 SP3 database (that updates thousands of records). This update statement is sent via odbc. After each (of multiple) tries, the update fails after about 5 mintues with:

```
S1000 General Error
```

I suspected that maybe some of "the record to be updated" were locked. So I rebooted the server and ran the update statement again. Then, it succeeded.

Is there way to tell Pervasive PSQL to ignore locked records during an standard SQL Update Statement? In my use-case, it is ok if locked records are ignored, but I need to be sure that at least the unlocked records get updated each time this statement runs.

Also, I'd like to accomplish this without a script or stored procedure; I'd like to accomplish this with a SQL update statement. I've used other database where you could append something onto the end of the statement to indicate how locks should be handled, but I can't find how to do this in Pervasive PSQL.

Comment: What tool are you using to execute the query?  Is there any thing else with the error?  A "general error" is very generic.  It could be a deadlock or it could be a timeout.  It's hard to say for sure.  Is the "other" application that's accessing the database using SQL or Btrieve calls?

Comment: Exactly, that genericness isn't helpful. [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io) is sending a SQL update statement via ODBC, set up with the pervasive client-driver. I get that error after 5 minutes. However, if I reboot the server, and send the same query (the same way), it succeeds in 15 seconds. How can't I tell pervasive to ignore locked records during in a SQL update statement? Obviously, I can't always reboot the server (to unlock records) each time this SQL statement needs to run.

Comment: If you run the same UPDATE through the Pervasive Control Center(PCC) does it behave the same?  Both the PCC and DBeaver use JDBC (rather than ODBC).  As far as I know, there isn't anything you can add to the query that would cause Pervasive to ignore locks.

Comment: @mirtheil Probably not helpful either, but I updated my question to show the error PCC produces also.

Comment: I don't see any edit for the PCC error.  Regardless, as far as I know there's no way to tell PCC to ignore locks from within a SQL statement. What I would suggest would be to write a program that uses DTI/DTO to disconnect users and then execute your query and schedule the program during down time.